# Exercise 2.10 from The C Programming Language

Tags: c

I am a new programmer and was wondering if someone could point out where my code is going wrong here.

I am trying to complete exercise 2.10 from **The C Programming Language**.

I need to make a function `lower()` which converts up case to lower case using the condition expression, however my code does not work: the test string is output unchanged as `Test String` where I expected the output to be `test string`.

Here is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void lower(char string[]);

int main(void) {
    char string[] = "Test String";

    lower(string);

    printf("%s\n", string);
}

void lower(char string[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i != '\0'; i++) {
        string[i] = (string[i] >= 'A' && string[i] <= 'Z') ? (string[i] + 32) : string[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: `i != '\0'` - Look closely at this condition.

Comment: @RetiredNinja He's specifically trying to learn about ternaries.

Comment: Formally, you're not asking a question. You don't even describe a problem...

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
void lower(char string[]){
    for(int i = 0; i != '\0'; i++){
        string[i] = (string[i] >= 'A' && string[i] <= 'Z') ? (string[i] + 32) : string[i];
    }
}
```

Your loop should check whether `string[i]` is not the null terminator, rather than `i`.

Answer (score 1):

The code does not work because the test `i != '\0'` fails immediately as the initial value of `i` is `0`, which is equal to `'\0'`.

You mean to test for the null terminator at the end of the string with `string[i] != '\0'`.

What the body of the loop does is check if the character at offset `i` is lexicographically between `'A'` and `'Z'` inclusive, and adds `32` if true, thereby converting the uppercase ASCII letter to its lowercase equivalent. `32` is the offset between `'A'` and `'a'` and specifying this offset as `'a' - 'A'` would be more readable.

Note however that this old code assumes the ASCII encoding where the uppercase and lowercase letters form contiguous blocks 32 positions apart, which is not the case of some other encodings such as EBCDIC, which was still common at the time.

Here is a modified version:

```
void lower(char *s) {
    // assuming ASCII
    for (size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z')
            s[i] += 'a' - 'A';
    }
}
```